# Include images in Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

i have a problem, so i'll show it below. First, thanks for reading!

Im coding a Minesweeper game on Netbeans. In the code, i have to include images of numbers, bomb, flag...

First, i created a "images" folder in "src". Then I go Properties, and add Resources (It shown images folder in project).

My workscreen: https://flic.kr/p/qevcEm

Then this was important, i searched Google and use this code but got trouble.

```
public void imgmine() {
    String name;


    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        name = "images/" + i + ".png";
        ic[i] = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(name));   
         /// i was edit above line. but 9 10 11 12 13 wasnt.
    }
    ic[9] = new ImageIcon("bomb.png");
    ic[10] = new ImageIcon("flag.png");
    ic[11] = new ImageIcon("newgame.png");
    ic[12] = new ImageIcon("crape.gif");
    ic[13] = new ImageIcon("winner.gif");
}
```

No error in windows code. But Complier said:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)

    at Minesweeper.imgmine(Minesweeper.java:522)

    at Minesweeper.<init>(Minesweeper.java:43)

    at Main.main(Main.java:32)

Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

**Line 522 is**

```
ic[i] = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(name));
```

Comment: What is the FQN of `Minesweeper.class` ?

Comment: What is FQN sir? My English isnt good :(

Comment: [FQN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) like `my.package.game.Minesweeper` .

Comment: <default package> sir

Comment: @PeterMmm ic[9] 10 11 12 13 i want edit before. It cant be an issues because problem is the URL

Answer (score 2):

Use an absolute path, as `getClass().getResource(...)` gives as relative root the package's directory.

```
name = "/images/" + i + ".png";
```

P.S.

Aren't bomb.png and the others not in images/?

Comment: ic 9 10 11 12 13  >> i wasnt edit it. I tested at ic[i] first. The real image folder is : C:\Users\hieut_000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Minesweeper\src\images

Comment: In the resulting application jar (a zip archive), you should find the paths `/images/0.png` and those paths are for `Class.getResource`.

Comment: i think it cant be compiled by issues. So I cant found images folder in jar